# Make each result stored in a different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This dictionary:

The left side: `IAO,INOT_A`,etc are  dataframes and the right to them are the columns.

```
dict1 =({'IAO' :  ['N','OBD'] ,'INOT_A' : ['CIN','OTID'], 
          'IA_PST_S' : ['K','OBD'], 'IA' : ['K','jse']})
```

This code makes the `df` to be replaced in each loop in the last line (problem) :

```
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v))
    df.columns = v
    column_for_count =v[0]
    df['count_of_' + column_for_count]=[df[column_for_count].value_counts().loc[x] for x in df[column_for_count]]
```

How to make it get stored in a different df?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create dictionary of DataFrame, with keys by by original `dict1`:

```
dfs = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(k, v))
    df.columns = v
    column_for_count =v[0]
    df['count_of_' + column_for_count]=[df[column_for_count].value_counts().loc[x] for x in df[column_for_count]]
    dfs[k] = df
```

Then for select each `DataFrame` use:

```
print (dfs['IAO'])
```

Comment: This is probably great, I will experiment and report soon.

Comment: @user51332 - sure, testing is always important.

Comment: @jezrael, thank you for as usual great code and solutions, request you to please add some explanation so that newbie like me could get more knowledge from it too. Will be grateful to you, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - This solution populate empty dictionary in loop by code `dictionary[key] = value`